# 500 error when including Paramiko in python script running on Apache web server

Tags: python, apache, paramiko

The following script generates a 500 internal error when I try to access is via a web browser.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi
import cgitb
import paramiko

cgitb.enable()   # Enable error messages

print "Content-Type: text/html"    # HTML will follow
print ""

print "<html><head></head><body>Done.</body></html>"
```

The script runs without an error if I execute it from the linux command line.

If I comment out the "import paramiko" line, it runs fine in the web browser.

I know that paramiko is installed and working because it is used by other command line scripts. This is my first attempt to use paramiko from a script accessed by a web interface.

I don't see any errors in the /var/log/httpd/error_log file.

Where should I be looking to fix this issue?

I'm running Centos 5-10.el5, with apache v 2.2.3-83.el5 and python 2.7.2.

Comment: apache is likely run under user `httpd`. Maybe `paramiko` is not installed properly for this user ?

Comment: I can't find any way to run my script as user apache to test if it is a user permissions issue. There is no httpd user:

`# su -c /bin/bash apache
This account is currently not available.`

Comment: Not sure what has changed, but now when I try to access my script via a web browser I am receiving an error from Python telling me that there is no module "paramiko" to be found.  Again, the script does work when run from the linux command line. Something else I just noticed... the python version in the error message is 2.4.3, yet from the command line python reports that it is version 2.7.2.  Why would apache run a different version of python that my linux bash command line?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the first line in my script to:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

...resolved my issues. The web scripts now use the same python that I get when running scripts from the command line.